# Make div slideDown() while other content fadeIn()

Tags: jquery

How could I make the div in this code slide down smoothly while the other content is fading in, and then slide up smoothly as the other content is fading out, based upon the selection from the dropdown menu.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jM54b/9/)

```
$("select[name='monthSelect']").prop('disabled', true);
$("select[name='catFrequency']").change(function () {
var jSelect1 = $("select[name='monthSelect']");
if (jSelect1.prop('disabled')) {
    jSelect1.removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#recurBegin').find("option[value='']").remove();
    $('#recurEnd').find("option[value='']").remove();
    $('#recurEnd').find("option[value='12']").prop('selected', true);
} else {
    jSelect1.prop('disabled', true);
    $("#recurBegin").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
    $("#recurEnd").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
}
});
var end = $('#recurEnd');
$('#recurBegin').change(function () {
if (this.value == 12) {
        end.val(12);
    end.prop('disabled', true);
} else {
    var index = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
    end.prop('disabled', false);
    end.find('option').show();
    end.find('option:lt(' + (index + 1) + ')').hide();
    end.find('option:eq(' + ++index + ')').prop('selected', true);
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Jquery:**

```
$("#select").change(function () {

if($(this).val() == 0)
{
    $('.subHeader').fadeOut(500);
    $('#annual').hide('slow');        
}
else
{
    $('.subHeader').fadeIn(500);
    $('#annual').show('slow');
}

});
```

**CSS:**

```
.hide {
    display:none;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/jM54b/13/)

Comment: this works in the demo, but not in my actual project...any ideas where i could begin investigating the cause of that?  I've got that code after the footer in script tags.

Comment: @user1476992 I forgot to tell you, Have a look at the css in that demo.

Comment: yes, I did see that you had changed the CSS.  The problem has to be something in my code.  The weird thing is that I already had a script that worked, I was just trying to make it a more fluid transition, so its weird that yours wouldn't work.   I'm going to have to just come back to it later I guess.  thanks for your help though!